# Create a flow field with fully customizable arrows in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to produce a flow field map in Python which should be perfectly readable for people with colorblindness. Just like the image on the [following page](https://www.bsh.de/DE/DATEN/Stroemungen/stroemungen_node.html;jsessionid=4E2E81AE6BA1F3AB6499884FA7028629.live11294) (created with GMT):
[image]

My data is in `netcdf` format, the flow vectors are in `u` and `v` components and I am plotting it on a meshgrid(`lon`, `lat`) with `plt.quiver`.
The problem with quiver is that you just can control the colors ond not the style of arrows.
I have a workaround with windbarbs (`plt.barbs`), however it would be much better to include custom arrows for specific data values.

Is there a way in python to include different arrow styles?
Or is there a possibility to include arrow styles for specific data ranges?

Comment: You could use Selenium through Python to create charts using the web application you cite...

Comment: I think this is a valid question! I wrote a small function to achieve this and would be glad if this question will be reopened. See [here](https://imgur.com/a/BlFkNw2).

Comment: @duhaime thanks for the tip, i will check it out!

Comment: @scleronomic that very near the result I am hoping for. Did you build up your own arrows and assigned them to data ranges ? I hope the question will be reopened. I edited the question according to the stack overflow rules.

Comment: Yes that's what I did. For the meantime I posted the code [here](https://justpaste.it/9jptc).

Comment: @scleronomic thanks for the help so far. I will try to implement it into my code.